# Android UI guidance :)

Tags: android, user-interface

Okay I will start by saying this is a conceptual question.

Consider this example:

http://www.pinterest.com/pin/135671007499038545/

**Firstly**, see the top BUILD YOUR OWN part. I want that to be static. In the sense that that is always there from first page to last page. Even when I change pages. That should not move or fade, only whatever is below that should change. How do I implement this. Do I make the top header a LinearLayout. Then how do I switch to a different app page keeping the top header static?

**Secondly**, see the section of SHIRTS and PANTS and whatever.... is it a ListView of LinearLayouts? Or is there a better way to approach this?

**Last thing**, see the kind of blurred shadow under each topic in QuizUp(link given below), how do I get it. It is probably made in HTML5/CSS3 using PhoneGap. But can it be done in native android?

Link for third question image:

http://yalsa.ala.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/quizuptopics.jpg

Now for the second and third question telling me how to do it is fine. But for the first question I'd appreciate a code snip or a tutorial or GitHub link, if possible.

Thank You so much :D

Comment: Might want to read up on [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: For question 1, you _could_ just set the title bar for the activity to say whatever you wanted as shown [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Comment: `First`, it could be an ActionBar. `is it a ListView of LinearLayouts?` No, of TextViews (with a **compound drawable** on the left side). `3` You can make the shadowed boxes by using **9 patches**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIRST** You can use a global `LinearLayout` with a `RelativeLayout` for your top bar and use a `ViewPager` for the content. You will then add `Fragments` to your `ViewPager` if you want many screens for your content (with static top bar). Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout> <!-- Top Bar -->
    <ViewPager/> <!-- Content -->
</LinearLayout>
```

**SECOND** You can use a single special `ListView` with categories for the shirts/shoes/whatever that goes in a single `Fragment` contained in your `ViewPager`. This might be a little complicated. You can use this: https://github.com/JimiSmith/PinnedHeaderListView

**THIRD** Yes it can be done in native, just specify your own list row view for your `ListView`. You can probably add an `ImageView` for each row that acts as the shadow. Or maybe android has it built in.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Android does not have a built in BLURRED shadow effect. As far as I know. Adding seperate ImageView does not seem syntactically correct.

What is a ViewPager? I have no Idea. Is it like a box to display different XML layouts?

Comment: A ViewPager is basically a layout manager. In the sense that you can add fragments inside of it and it has an automatic swipe-to-change-screen functionality in it. For more information, check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: Thanks man. I'll try to implement it and let you know. If I get stuck please do help me. BTW that pinterest link is not mine. I was just referencing it. :D

Comment: Np! Feel free to accept this answer or thumbs up if this worked! Other users may also find it useful :)